# C: Change elements of struct in (Array of Structs) by pointer reference to a function

Tags: c

I have  an array of structs:

```
typedef struct custom_struct
{
    bool my_bool;
    float my_float;
    char my_text[100];
} custom_struct;

custom_struct my_struct[] = {
        {false, 1.0, "text_1"},
        {false, 2.0, "text_2"},
        {false, 3.0, "text_3"},
        {false, 4.0, "text_4"},
        {false, 5.0, "text_5"},
    };
```

now, for the function (partial?) pseudo code:

```
// function called:
toggle_state(0, &my_struct);

// pseudo func definition
void toggle_state(int idx ,custom_struct (*p)[])
{
if ((*p)[idx].my_bool == true)
    {
        (*p)[idx].my_bool = false;
    }
    else
    {
        (*p)[idx].my_bool = true;
    }
}
```

I want to change the elements of the **nth idx** of the my_struct by passing a (pointer of my_struct) to a function.
Does this increase efficiency if called a 100000+ times in a loop?
Is there a better method to solve this?

Edited through comments:

Changed to make it compile: `*p` to `(*p)[]` - by Jasn Liam

Changed internal func of toggle - by 0________

Comment: choose **one** language. There is no C/C++ one

Comment: First things first, `toggle_state(0, &my_struct);` won't compile because function parameter type is `custom_struct*` and you're passing argument `&my_struct` which is of type `custom_struct (*)[5]`.

Comment: do not post "pseudocode" with *"obviously"* not C syntax only minimal example which can be compiled and tested by us.

Comment: What exactly are you asking ? Whether it is more efficient to use a function for toggling a `bool` in an array of structs ? Adding a function can theoretically be **less** efficient (not more) due to the cost of a function calls, but in this case it can easily be inlined by the compiler and thus be identical performance-wise.

Comment: Apologies to @JasonLiam and @0 for the inaccurate question. Allow me to clarify: 
I want to find the best method to modify and access the values of my_struct by passing the pointer to those menory locations as arguements to the functions without copying data. Is there an efficient method to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a pointer to the array? That is more complicated than needed. Just pass a pointer to the struct.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I want to iterate over the array and access the struct by length of array.

Comment: You don't need a **pointer to array** to do that.... it is as simple as https://ideone.com/tf99rz

Comment: @SupportUkraine wouldn't `p[idx].my_bool` be inefficient than something like `p[idx]->my_bool`?

Comment: No. If there are any difference worth mentioning, I'm pretty sure that `p[idx].my_bool` is fastest. Why do you expect the other to be faster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247984/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-j-and-support-ukraine).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SupportUkraine for the answer and explanation. The explanation is in the discussion under the commments of the question.

> when you just use the array name in a function call, it is in fact converted to a pointer so it is not the whole array data that are passed to the function... just a pointer

> If you pass a single struct variable (instead of an array) then all the struct members are copied and that can be bad for performance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct custom_struct
{
    bool my_bool;
    float my_float;
    char my_text[100];
} custom_struct;


void toggle_state(int idx , custom_struct *p)
{
    p[idx].my_bool = !p[idx].my_bool;
}

int main(void) 
{
    custom_struct my_struct[] = {
        {false, 1.0, "text_1"},
        {false, 2.0, "text_2"},
        {false, 3.0, "text_3"},
        {false, 4.0, "text_4"},
        {false, 5.0, "text_5"},
    };
    
    printf("my_struct[2].my_bool is %s\n", my_struct[2].my_bool ? "true" : "false");

    toggle_state(2, my_struct);
    
    printf("my_struct[2].my_bool is %s\n", my_struct[2].my_bool ? "true" : "false");
    
    return 0;
}
```